# How to transfer tf.keras trained model to caffe with same prediction result

Tags: python, tensorflow, caffe, tf.keras

Has anyone tried to transfer keras model to caffe???

I’ve trained my keras model using the net structure build based on tf.keras(2.2.4-tf), and I need to transfer this trained .h5 model to caffemodel and prototxt.

I have tried the keras2caffe project (github.com/uhfband/keras2caffe) and successfully get the caffemodel and prototxt. But the predict results of keras and caffe is totally different.

Is there any other way can let me get the correct transferred caffe model ?

The environment I’m using is as following.

Tensorflow 1.15.0

Tensorflow.keras 2.2.4-tf

Caffe 1.0.0

Numpy 1.18.1

cv2 3.4.3

Comment: You may try https://github.com/onnx/onnx

Comment: I have tried transfer the model to ONNX , but failed to transfer the onnx model to caffemodel.